# Text flowing under image

Tags: html, css

I have the search bar and an image("Debian" written on it) in my nav bar, it looks something like this.
[image]

so, when I search something in my search bar, the results are going below the image something like this.
[image]
I want these results to come over the image so that each result can be seen properly. and there is one more thing that, see when I have nothing entered in my search bar is still showing me the results, so how to fix these issues?
my HTML code looks something like this...

```
<div class="search_box" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input required type="text" id="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Anything">
            <ul id="search-results" class="list-group" style="position:absolute;">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: use higher z-index value for your dropdown.

Comment: it worked for the first problem but what about the second problem of showing the search results even when box is left empty..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) use higher css `z-index` value for your dropdown.

2) to hide the search results when there is no data, add an `if condition` checking for empty.